# How to exclude some particular files in Pc-lint

Tags: lint, pc-lint

While running pclint for a particular folder, its running for all the files inside that folder. If we want the pclint to omit some of the files, then how to configure it in `std.lnt` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, your std.lnt file does not contain a list of source file names to be processed. You then call PC Lint with the command line

```
<path>/lint-nt.exe std.lnt file1 [file2...]
```

where file file is a C or C++ source file (not a header file).

Since Lint seems to process all the source files in you folder, take a look at your std.lnt file and see if there's a list of *.c/*.cpp files included. Remove them.
Then build your command line as above, and list just the files you are interested in; or "*.c" to again process all the C files in the current directory.

If you need more guidance as to how to structure and create your Lint option files, google for ["How to wield PC Lint"](http://www.bezem.de/pdf/htwpl.pdf), first result, which is my whitepaper on how to setup PC Lint if the setup.exe just doesn't thrill you much.