# How could PC-lint ignore/suppress warnings from Google Protocol buffer headers?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, pc-lint

I'm using the PC-lint on my project which uses the Google protocol buffer.

The PC-lint generates too many warnings related to `xxx.pb.h`.

Is there any configuration to set something like "header whitelist" to prevent this?

I know for `clang-tidy`, it supports doing so by passing the `-header-filter`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude some particular files in Pc-lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816984/how-to-exclude-some-particular-files-in-pc-lint)

Answer (score 0):

This already has an answer in [How to exclude some particular files in Pc-lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816984/how-to-exclude-some-particular-files-in-pc-lint)

However, a word of caution in such a blanket exclusion... in amongst the noise, there may be warnings that are pertinent to your usage.  Therefore, I suggest that you do (at least) one full assessment pass of the warnings/errors before you decide to ignore them all.

All warnings are there for a reason!

I appreciate you are not using [misra](/questions/tagged/misra), but [MISRA Compliance](https://www.misra.org.uk/app/uploads/2021/06/MISRA-Compliance-2020.pdf) has the concept of *adopted code* (such as the headers you refer) and gives guidance on what to do.  I commend it to your consideration.

To repeat: any warnings/errors you get are there for a reason... understanding *why* you get the violation is important!  And disabling specific notifications would be better than a blanket ignore all.